# Form submitting without checking mandatory field in ext js

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs3

I added some fields in an ext js form with required 'itemCls'. But the form submitting without checking (mandatory fields) the fields null or not.

My code is given below,

```js
  xtype: 'form',
  id: 'form',
  bodyStyle: 'overflow : auto; height: 337px;',
  items: [{
    xtype: 'fieldset',
    items: [{
      xtype: 'combo',
      id: 'adr',
      anchor: '98%',
      listWidth: 300,
      itemCls: 'required',
      editable: false,
      store: store,
      displayField: 'NAM',
      valueField: 'ID',
      triggerAction: 'all',
      mode: 'local'
    }, {
      xtype: 'datefield',
      id: 'date',
      name: 'date',
      itemCls: 'required',
      readOnly: false,
    }, {
      xtype: 'textfield',
      id: 'name',
      itemCls: 'required',
      anchor: '98%',
      fieldLabel: 'name',
      name: 'name'
    }]
  }, {
    xtype: 'button',
    text: 'Save',
    handler: function(btn, evt) {
      Ext.getCmp('form').getForm().submit();
    }

  }]
```

Any help is must appreciated..

Comment: try adding `allowBlank : false` to form fields. check api docs http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/3-4/#!/api/Ext.form.TextField-cfg-allowBlank

Comment: Look at the http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19658102/how-to-check-few-form-fields-are-empty-or-not

Answer (score 0):

You have to add [monitorValid](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/3-4/#!/api/Ext.form.FormPanel-cfg-monitorValid): true to **form**. Then you can use listener [clientvalidation](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/3-4/#!/api/Ext.form.FormPanel-event-clientvalidation) on **form**, for exmaple, to disable submit button

```
listeners: {
  clientvalidation : function(form, valid) {
    Ext.getCmp('button-save').setDisabled(!valid);
  }
}
```

After that client validation will work as expected. NOTE: **button-save** is **id** which should be on **Save** button.